# Retrieve Tkinter Checkbutton Status : TclError: can't read "PY_VAR": no such variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am using `Tkinter` in a basic Python 2.7 GUI application and I would like to retrieve the `Checkbutton` widget status (checked/unchecked) by using a `IntVar` but I am getting the following error.

```
TclError: can't read "PY_VAR": no such variable
```

I have followed the example on [effbot about the Checkbutton Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm) and I am using a different `IntVar` for each button and using a `callback` function to print the variable by calling the `getvar` function on the buttons.

My only goal is to view a status of the `Checkbutton` widget.

I am using the Tkinter Grid Geometry manger to place the widgets on the GUI. Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that produces the error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as tk

class Frame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.buttons = dict() #number to button widget
        self.createWidgets(master)

    def printvar(self, button_number):
        print self.buttons[button_number].getvar()

    def createWidgets(self,master):
        for n in range(0,4):
            var = tk.IntVar()
            button = tk.Checkbutton(
                master,
                variable=var,
                command=lambda bn=n: self.printvar(bn)
            )
            button.grid(row=0, column=n)
            self.buttons[n] = button

window = Frame(tk.Tk())
window.mainloop()
```

The code makes four numbered buttons passing the number to a `lambda` function which looks up the button in a `dict` and calls its corresponding `getvar` function.

If you run the example code it will produce the following error when you check any of the four buttons. It is in a file named `tktest.py`

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./tktest.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    command=lambda bn=n: self.printvar(bn)
  File "./tktest.py", line 12, in printvar
    print self.buttons[button_number].getvar()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 513, in getvar
    return self.tk.getvar(name)
TclError: can't read "PY_VAR": no such variable
```

There is no `var` variable for each button and I am therefore calling the  `getvar` method.

Any alternative methodology for checking each individual `Checkbutton` widget status would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: First create n number of var for use and than asign for each button and save in a list.

```
def createWidgets(self,master):
    self.vars=[]
    for n in range(0,4):
        var = tk.IntVar()
        self.vars.append(var)

    for n in range(0,4):
        button = tk.Checkbutton(
            master,
            variable=self.vars[n],
            command=lambda bn=n: self.printvar(bn)
        )
        button.grid(row=0, column=n)
        self.buttons[n] = button
```

and then you can change your method to this for call the var for the number

```
def printvar(self, button_number):
    print "The button:{} is {}".format(button_number,self.vars[button_number].get())
```

The output for example is:

```
The button:2 is 0
The button:2 is 1
```

when 0 is unchecked and 1 checked

Comment: gonna try this out, will let you know